# Reading Spam Folder Messages with Gmail IMap

Tags: python, gmail, gmail-imap

I have this code to use gmail imap to check unread messages, and it works good to read messages in the inbox, but I also want to read messages in the spam folder. I am not sure how I would go about this. I also only want to continue to only read Unseen messages like the script does now.  Any help or any possible solution is appreciated. This is what I have so far (this will only check inbox, not spam, I need to check unread in both):

```
import imaplib
import os

def check_emails(email):
    output = []
    try:
        M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
        M.login(email.split(":")[0], email.split(":")[1])
        M.select()
        M.select("Inbox")
        status, data = M.search(None, "UNSEEN")
        for num in data[0].split():
            status, data = M.fetch(num, '(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])')
            email_msg = data[0][1]
            output.append(email_msg)

        return output
    except Exception as e:
        return e.args



emails = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open(os.path.abspath("emails.txt"), 'r')]

for email in emails:
    print("Checking email " + email)
    print(check_emails(email))
```

Comment: Have you tried with `[Google Mail]/Spam` in the Select field?

Comment: @Jescanellas that does not work, it gives this error: ("SELECT command error: BAD [b'Could not parse command']",)

Answer (score 1):

For old Gmail accounts it's `[Google Mail]/Spam` for newer `[Gmail]/Spam`.

Best would be to find that detail out by listing available boxes and then finding

```js
   const boxes = await _imapConnection.getBoxes();
   console.log(boxes);
```

This will give you list of available boxes:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I have been trying to use [Google Mail]/ in the search, but it is actually [Gmail]/Spam.

Comment: yup, iirc it depends on how old gmail account is

Answer (score 0):

```html
def list_folders():
  host = 'your host'
  port = '993'
  email = 'your email'
  password = 'your password'
  
  import imaplib
  imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host, port)
  imap.login(email, password)
  raw_answer = imap.list()

''' The return value looks like this:
('OK', 
    [
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Deleted Items"', 
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Drafts', 
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" INBOX', 
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Junk E-mail"', 
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Notes', 
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "Sent Items"', 
        b'(\\HasNoChildren) "/" Public'
    ]
)
'''

  if raw_list[0] == "OK":
    answer_body = raw_list[1]
    body_parts = []
    for part in answer_body:
      part = part.decode('utf-8')
      parts.append(part.split('"/"')[1])
      
  return parts
  
''' Which looks like this:
[' "Deleted Items"', ' Drafts', ' INBOX', ' "Junk E-mail"', ' Notes', ' "Sent Items"', ' Public']
'''
```

The return values are still not pretty. You can see " and ' being useless there but some ifs can fix it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).